# Android successful built gradle but not install apps on emulator

Tags: java, android

I was having some problem with Android Architecture Component. What I am trying to do is from the view model, I will execute the functions inside repository class. Here is my view model:

```
private final ReservationRepository reservationRepository;
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private LiveData<List<ReservationEntity>> reservations;

@Inject
public ReservationViewModel(ReservationRepository reservationRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.reservationRepository = reservationRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    reservations = reservationRepository.loadReservations();
}

public LiveData<List<ReservationEntity>> getAllReservations() {
    return reservations;
}
```

Then in my repository class:

```
private final ReservationDao reservationDao;

@Inject
public ReservationRepository(ReservationDao reservationDao) {
    this.reservationDao = reservationDao;
}

public LiveData<List<ReservationEntity>> loadReservations() {
    return reservationDao.getAllReservation();
}
```

In my DAO class:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM reservation")
LiveData<List<ReservationEntity>> getAllReservation();
```

I got one AppModule to @Provide the @Inject:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ReservationDatabase provideReservationDatabase(Application application) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(application,ReservationDatabase.class,
            ReservationDatabase.DATABASE_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ReservationDao provideReservationDao(ReservationDatabase reservationDatabase) {
    return reservationDatabase.reservationDao();
}
```

I managed to build the project successfully. However, after successfully built gradle, it does not install the apps onto the emulator. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the error message or Screen shot of your Error message !

Comment: @Pie there is no error message at all. It just won't build :(

Comment: If you have existing app on emulator.Uninstall it and try to run the app again!

Comment: I am getting this error message: Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view. But then my gradle build was successful

Comment: Downvoter mind to explain?

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 26):

In my case, a `Gradle Sync` solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following to resolve your problem

- You can turn off the instant Run.

  File>Settings>Build , Execution , Deployment>Instant Run>Uncheck the Instant Run.

After that try to run your app on emulator again.

- Restart Android studio

  File->Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Perform Clean Build

  Build->Clean Project
- Try to Sync your project

  File-> Sync project
- Make sure Project location does not contain the special character.

  E:\Android_Projects\T&PUIET,KUK\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

  close android studio > rename folder containing the special character(here T&PUIET,KUK ) > restart android studio.

Hope this Solution helps!

Comment: I suspect it is something to do with the @inject but I not sure why is it so. Because if I don't inject to the repository but rather initiating the database from view model directly, it managed to build and run.

Comment: Dot character in path was causing this issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

in my "dumb - case" i didn't have a `launcher activity`, add this to the first one :

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I appreciate the dumb case answer, because this just happened to me too :)

Answer (score 2):

As @David Miguel Say that just do sync project with Gradle.

I do my problem solved.

Just use All search in my case Linux then I do  double Shift press.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.In Android Studio go to Build>Build APK(s)
Then find the apk file of your app at 
[project-location]\app\build\outputs\apk\debug

2.Open command prompt or terminal(for MAC) of your PC and type
cd C:\Users[user-name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

It may vary if location of your installed SDK is different.

3.Then copy paste the generated apk in step1 at the location in step2.

4. Then run  adb install [generated apk name]

This should install apk in your emulator. Just make sure no other device is connected and no other emulator is running other than where you want to install it.

Comment: I am getting this error message: Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view. Where is the 'Messages' view though

Answer (score 0):

[Behavior changes: Apps targeting Android 12!](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

> Warning: If an activity, service, or broadcast receiver uses intent
> filters and doesn't have an explicitly-declared value for
> android:exported, your app can't be installed on a device that runs
> Android 12.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on physical device) I had to change android:exported from false to true in AndroidManifest.xml othervice device is not able to open app installed by android studio (app icon appears on devie but clicking = app isnt installed)

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ... >
        <activity ... android:exported="true" >
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, syncing Gradle and other answers didn't help. Because my problem was pretty idiotic. I didn't let the android studio to generate MainActivity when creating the project, so I had to generate the class and the layout manually. But I misplaced assigning the MainActivity to manifest file using the the tag `<activity... </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Make Project** option under Build.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).